# is one to many and many to one bi-directional the same as many to many?

Tags: hibernate

is one to many and many to one bi-directional also the same way to implement many to many in hibernate?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEM")
public class Item { ... } // no relational mapping here

@Entity
@Table(name = "CART")
public class Cart {
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Item1.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "CART_ITEMS", //  name of physical database table
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id") }, 
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "item_id") })
    private Set<Item1> items;
}
```

By using mappedBy, I only have two physical tables (ITEM and CART):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEM")
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne(name = "cart", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Cart cart;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CART")
public class Cart {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<Item> items;
}
```

But by using @JoinTable, the physical table joining the two would also be CART_ITEMS. same as many to many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEM")
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne(name = "cart", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Cart cart;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CART")
public class Cart {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable( name = "CART_ITEMS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CART_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID") )
    private Set<Item> items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there are differences in both the database tables created and the constraints added to those tables. In your first case, `@ManyToMany`, the three tables created are the Cart, the Item and the CartItem join table:

```
create table CART1 (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table CART1_ITEMS1 (cart1_id bigint not null, item1_id bigint not null, primary key (cart1_id, item1_id))
create table ITEM1 (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
```

The constraints allow for `ManyToMany` mapping, requiring only that entries point to existing entries in the Cart or Item table:

```
alter table CART1_ITEMS1 add constraint FK_rp3ydw070costp3hxxipfdepm foreign key (item1_id) references ITEM1
alter table CART1_ITEMS1 add constraint FK_lj0kor79pdsabd7oeuvpbc1vv foreign key (cart1_id) references CART1
```

In the OneToMany bidirectional tables, the tables are almost the same, except that the Item table has a `foreign key` for the cart table in it.

```
create table CART3 (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table CART3_ITEMS3 (CART3_ID bigint not null, ITEM3_ID bigint not null, primary key (CART3_ID, ITEM3_ID))
create table ITEM3 (id bigint not null, cart3_id bigint, primary key (id))
```

And the constraints include a `unique` constraint that prevents any `Item` from referencing more than one `Cart` :

```
alter table CART3_ITEMS3 add constraint UK_kmbin3nr6yh9pn8p11vfd75rf  unique (ITEM3_ID)
alter table CART3_ITEMS3 add constraint FK_kmbin3nr6yh9pn8p11vfd75rf foreign key (ITEM3_ID) references ITEM3
alter table CART3_ITEMS3 add constraint FK_8mjsk05vejc18afjorn4d8gbw foreign key (CART3_ID) references CART3
```

as well as a constraint on the `Item` table that requires a valid `Cart` reference.

```
alter table ITEM3 add constraint FK_exbk5pj0g8jllcxfsvmsr88if foreign key (cart3_id) references CART3
```

Hope this helps.